# SQL Select Day IN and Day OUT grouped by ID's

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to GROUP EIDs by dates  where Date between 2014-01-15  and 2014-03-18

```
| ID |EID  |      DATE    |  Status |     |
|----------|--------------|---------|-----|
|  9 |9991 | 2014-03-16   |     OUT |     |
|  8 |9997 | 2014-03-18   |     IN  |     |
|  7 |9997 | 2014-03-16   |     OUT |     |
|  6 |9999 | 2014-02-16   |     IN  |     |
|  5 |9999 | 2014-02-16   |     OUT |     |
|  4 |9996 | 2014-03-18   |     IN  |     |
|  3 |9996 | 2014-03-16   |     OUT |     |
|  2 |9997 | 2014-01-18   |     IN  |     |
|  1 |9997 | 2014-01-15   |     OUT |     |
```

Output should be like:

```
|  
|EID   |in date       |   OUT date|  DAYS OUT |  
|------|--------------|---------  |------ ----|
| 9997 | 2014-03-18   | 2014-03-16|      2    |
| 9997 | 2014-01-18   | 2014-01-15|      3    |
| 9999 | 2014-02-16   | 2014-02-16|      0    |
| 9996 | 2014-03-18   | 2014-03-16|      2    |
| 9991 |              | 2014-03-16|           |
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one method that assumes that they are interleaved, so no two ins or outs are together:

```
select eid,
       max(case when status = 'in' then date end) as in_date,
       max(case when status = 'out' then date end) as out_date,
       datediff(day,
                max(case when status = 'in' then date end),
                max(case when status = 'out' then date end)
               ) as days_diff
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by eid, status order by date) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by eid, seqnum;
```

Comment: Check out your code again. Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.
Incorrect syntax near 't'.

Comment: You don't need to aliases inside the `DATEDIFF()` function

Comment: Even so, it's not what the OP want and the `out_date` will be always `NULL`

Answer (score -2):

I think that you have already done it but, have you tried to do the sentence like:

SELECT [here you format as you wish] FROM [your table] WHERE date BETWEEN '2014-01-15' AND '2014-03-18' GROUP BY date

or

SELECT [here you format as you wish] FROM [your table] WHERE dateIn >= '2014-01-15' AND dateOut <= '2014-03-18' GROUP BY dateIn

Can you share your full table?